# Error connecting python container to SQL server using pyodbc?

Tags: python, sql-server, docker, containers, pyodbc

I'm trying to connect a python container with SQL management studio in my host (Windows). I'm using port 1444 that is the port of my database and it give me this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    connection = pyodbc.connect('Driver={FreeTDS};'
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08S01', '[08S01] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (20009) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

The main.py code is:

```
import pyodbc

connection = pyodbc.connect('Driver={FreeTDS};'
                            'Server=DESKTOP-xxx\SQLEXPRESS,1444;'
                            'Database=DBxx;'
                            'UID=username;'
                            'PWD=password')

cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT [Id],[c1] FROM [DBxx].[dbo].[TABLExx]")
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print(row.Name)
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python

EXPOSE 1444
WORKDIR /app

ADD requirements.txt .
ADD . /app
ADD odbcinst.ini /etc/odbcinst.ini

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install gcc -y
RUN apt-get install -y tdsodbc unixodbc-dev
RUN apt install unixodbc -y
RUN apt-get clean -y
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN echo "[FreeTDS]\n\
Description = FreeTDS Driver\n\
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so\n\
Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so" >> /etc/odbcinst.ini

# Run app.py when the container launches
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

And finally the requirements:

```
pyodbc
```

Comment: You're confusing a bunch of terms, I think.  SSMS is the _client_ app commonly used to query and manage SQL Server.  A container is a container, just something is running inside it.  It sounds like you're trying to run a python script on your PC, and it is supposed to connect to SQL Server running inside the container.  Is that correct?

Comment: Why do you specify both the instance name (`\SQLEXPRESS`) and a port number (`1444`)? Do you know the Express instance is running on port 1444? How/why? Have you verified the service is running?

Comment: When i create the container, python script is inside and it's trying to connect SQL. The port number is 1444 because thats the TCP port to the server.

Comment: The short version: Docker is really... poor... at handling UDP traffic between the host and containers, particularly when multiple NICs are involved (e.g.: Ethernet and Wifi), so avoid it at all costs.

Comment: The longer version: when you include an Instance Name in your connection string the client must use the SQL Server Resolution Protocol to communicate with the SQL Browser service on the target server (e.g.: Docker host) over udp/1434. The client sends the instance name and receives the TCP port number that instance is listening on, then uses that TCP port number to connect to the instance. Docker has a multitude of issues routing UDP traffic between containers and host so you're better off looking up the port number in SQL Server Configuration Manager and using that in your connection string.

Comment: Do you have SQL Server Express installed on your Windows host? Which version? Inside SQL Server (version) Configuration Manager, in the Server Protocols, is the TCP/IP protocol enabled? Which port(s) is it enabled to listen on?

Comment: You may also need to edit the `/etc/freetds/freetds.conf` file inside your Docker container and change the `[global]` setting away from `tds version = auto`. For SQL Server 2012 and later set it to `tds version = 7.4`, anything before SQL Server 2012 is no longer supported but use the TDS Version that matches your SQL Server version [shown here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tds/135d0ebe-5c4c-4a94-99bf-1811eccb9f4a).